# Error Running Development Web Server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am new to learning *AngularJS*, after installing *Node.js* I also cloned the `angular.phonecat` repository, I am finding it difficult to start the development web server using:

```
   npm install
```

Please find attached the errors i got. [image: Error message while trying to run npm start]

Comment: Seems like you're missing python binaries, or at least did not set its windows PATH environment variable

Comment: Install python, go to its website download it and set path if you are using windows os. and try `npm install` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[Install Python 2.7.*](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/python-2.7.11.msi) , node-gyp is looking for it to be specified and can't find it.

If you want to use a different version of Python with NPM, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454199/how-to-use-a-different-version-of-python-during-npm-install).