# jhipster - gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2

Tags: python, jhipster

Below is the error that I get, when I try to generate a new project with JHipster:

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE
gyp verb check python version `C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "3.6.4\r\n"
gyp verb could not find "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

The rest is the stacktrace. The weird thing is I do have python installed and the environment variable is also set. My python version is "Python 3.6.4". Should I run it in Python 2? Is that the case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes node-gyp requires Python 2.7, so you could try the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454199/how-to-use-a-different-version-of-python-during-npm-install).

Alternatively, if you encounter this problem, it is probably due to node-sass and if you did not select Sass in JHipster options, you don't need it but still you get it because it's a transitive dependency from Angular, you can skip it by setting environment variables:

```
set SKIP_SASS_BINARY_DOWNLOAD_FOR_CI=true
set SKIP_NODE_SASS_TESTS=true
```

Another alternative is to use [JHipster devbox](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox).

Answer (score 11):

There is another workaround to this error:

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder.
2. Run `npm install --global windows-build-tools --save` in your command prompt.
3. Install node-sass using the command: `npm install node-sass@4.12.0 --save` (or the latest version)

This should solve the error and return you a `gyp info ok` message!

If you encounter **`Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment`**, resolve it by running:

`npm rebuild node-sass`

Comment: Is windows-build-tools still a valid solution these days? Getting `npm WARN deprecated windows-build-tools@5.2.2: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.`

Comment: For me downgrading the node version to right version (as per my project) using `nvm` made this message go away and I was able to install the `windows-build-tools` using `npm`.

Answer (score 7):

Just a note for anyone using React and facing the same error on Linux (Ubuntu):

Step 1: Install python 2.7

- something similar to this

  ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install python2-minimal
  ```

Step 2: Install make or just build-essential

- something like:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential
  ```

Then you can proceed with your previous activity...

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this as well.

- I had to install Python 2.7 [Here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/)
- I also needed to downgrade my node version to 6.16 [Link to how to install and uninstall] (https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows)

Comment: This still seems relevant in 2021 on pretty up-to-date installations and versions of packages. Not sure why the underlying issue is not being fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change to older node version:

```
PS C:\> nvm list

    17.6.0
  * 16.13.2 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    15.0.0
    10.19.0
PS C:\> nvm use 10.19.0
Now using node v10.19.0 (64-bit)
```

Otherwise package `node-sass` failed to install. I did not investigate further why.