# Why does NVM use the incorrect version of Python?

Tags: python, node.js, macos, nvm

I'm having some issues with the `node-gyp` package, and I believe it's because I need to use python 2.7 rather than python 3.

I have set-up my PATH environment variables so that when I do `python --version` the output is `Python 2.7.16`.

However, in the same terminal, when I go to `yarn` install my project. It fails, and I can see the output of the logs is:

```
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/myname/Documents/myproject
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.5
gyp info using node@12.14.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/python"
```

I am also using nvm. Catalina 10.15.2. Node 12.14.0. NVM 0.33.11.

Why does my terminal version show me as using 2.7, but then the logs show the command `node-gyp rebuild` as using 3.7.3? If I've already set-up my environment variables, what can I change to rectify this? Is it something to do with nvm?

Answer (score 17):

If experiencing this issue on an M1 Mac, see the accepted answer to this question (basically for Node versions older than 15, you need to open Terminal using Rosetta):

[nvm install node fails to install on macOS Big Sur M1 Chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254339/nvm-install-node-fails-to-install-on-macos-big-sur-m1-chip)

This solution worked for me (on an M1 MacBook Pro) when the other answers here did not work.

Answer (score 8):

**MacOS M1**

1. Install `pyenv` with brew to manage different python versions: `brew install pyenv`.

2.`eval "$(pyenv init -)"`.

3. if you going install version lower than 3.y, open your terminal with rosetta.

   - Link bellow to instructions:
   - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9W8rTTE1WEA
4. List all installable versions with `pyenv install --list`
5. pyenv global 2.7.18

Answer (score -5):

Solved! You can do:

`npm install --python=python2.7`

or set it to be used always:

`npm config set python python2.7`

Pinched from here => [How to use a different version of python during NPM install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454199/how-to-use-a-different-version-of-python-during-npm-install)

Comment: It's for yarn.. If you think it's duplicate, mark it as duplicate. Don't just copy the answer..