# nvm install node fails to install on macOS Big Sur M1 Chip

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, npm-install, nvm

I'm trying to install the latest version of node using nvm. I've just got the newly released SIlicon Macbook Pro with the M1 chip (not sure if that is related). I've installed xcode on the app store and the xcode tools on the command line. The main error i'm getting is:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CXX=c++'
```

Comment: and they don't even have documentation for it anywhere.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

If you have installed `nvm` using `homebrew` and are trying to install the node using command `nvm install <some_version>`, you will face errors on apple silicon machines (ARM) for versions lower than 15. Node versions older than 15  do not work on apple silicon machines (ARM) because ARM architecture is not supported.
**For anything under v15, you will need to install node using Rosetta 2**.

1. How to open terminal in Rosetta2 mode: Go to Application -> Right click on terminal app -> Get Info -> Select "Open using Rosetta" -> Restart Terminal
2. In Terminal, write -> `arch -x86_64 zsh`

Now you will able to install any version of node (even multiple versions)

Comment: (nvm maintainer here) note that nvm is *explicitly* not supported when installed via homebrew - the only correct way to install it is with the install script in nvm's readme.

Comment: I am getting ```arch: posix_spawnp: zsh: Bad CPU type in executable```

Comment: I installed via the `nvm` install script and ran into the same error -- and the steps by @adityaatri to run Terminal or iTerm2 in Rosetta mode also worked for me.

Comment: if I understood correctly, you will neither do 1) OR 2), not together

Comment: I first needed to install Rosetta. This was all I did, WITHOUT opening the terminal using right click etc.

1. install nvm via the script at the github repo (not homebrew)
2. `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`
3. `arch -x86_64 zsh`
4. `nvm install 14.8.0`

Comment: Thanx alot, it saved me alot of time.

Comment: Step 1 was optional for me, Step 2 did the trick for me

Comment: can confirm this worked for me as well

Comment: Now my terminal line starts with `(base)` , how to exit this ? I tried with `arch -arm64 zsh`, no change.

Comment: @LJHarb This issue persists with the curl install as well.

Comment: @Jim in that case, please file an issue on the repo and fill out the entire issue template, and i'll be happy to take a look!

Answer (score 28):

it wasn't an issue while i was trying to install node 12.X.X but below that it was a big pain so i followed below steps and it worked for me

Uninstalled nvm if it’s already installed using Homebrew.

```
brew uninstall nvm
brew cleanup
```

Install Rosetta

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Make terminal/iTerm2 to open in Rosetta mode

got to Application (-> utilities) -> right click on terminal app -> get Info -> Select "Open using Rosetta" -> Restart Terminal

In Terminal run a command

```
arch -x86_64 zsh
```

Make sure machine has .zshrc file if not just create one

```
cd ~
touch .zshrc
```

Install NVM

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
```

Restart the terminal and check if nvm is installed successfully by running

```
nvm -v
```

Then install Node with nvm as usual

```
nvm install 10
```

Answer (score 12):

In 2023, this is quite simple. Install nvm in the normal way **without** using Rosetta.

Then install Rosetta which you can install by running in the macOS Terminal:

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Once installed, run

`arch -x86_64 zsh`

then if you want to install say 12

`nvm install lts/dubnium`

It will install, you can then use

`nvm use 12`

whenever you want to use 12, you don't have to do anything special to run it from here, it works without using `arch -x86_64 zsh`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Mar 2024 and this doesn't work with Node v14.21.3

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps if you have M1/M2 and you have installed nvm via homebrew

```
rm -rf ~/.nvm
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf ~/.bower

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

Run software update:
`softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`

Error in Rosetta Updater, but you can:
`grep RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg /var/log/install.log`

and just:
`open /path/to/RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg`

After that, right-click your terminal icon in dock > Open > Options > Show in Finder.

Then, right-click > Get Info.

Then, check 'Open using Rosetta'

In the terminal you can check you are using rosetta with:
`arch`

Then just:
`nvm install v6.9.1` # for example

Answer (score -1):

Install nvm version > 0.3.7 and install node version >= 16.0

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command for successful install:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
```

before the above command, please be sure to have `.zshrc` file in the root of your current username folder (`~/`).

Comment: This is to install nvm, not how to install a version of node using nvm