# I have issue in nodejs connect to database oracle in MacBook M1 max help me

Tags: node.js, oracle

Error message in nodejs
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Error:  Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(/Users/pitidev-ldb/Downloads/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/pitidev-ldb/Downloads/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/Users/pitidev-ldb/Downloads/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib.19.1' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help

Comment: Because there is no M1 port of the Oracle client libraries, you will need to use the Intel x86_64 Node.js binary with Oracle's macOS Intel Instant Client libraries.  Apple's Rosetta with then kick in.

Comment: pls recommend me what how to

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got things to work.

To install Node, Terminal needs to be run using Rosetta during installation. NVM will pick the specified version number as usual but opt for the x86_64 binaries instead of M1.

1. Installed `nvm` according to [NVMs own site](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating)
2. Followed this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70243924/2236725). What worked for me (read details in the post if things don't work out for you)

   1. Make terminal/iTerm2 to open in Rosetta mode. Got to `Applications (-> utilities) -> right click on terminal app -> get Info -> Select "Open using Rosetta" -> Restart Terminal`
   2. In Terminal.app run `arch -x86_64 zsh`
   3. From here install the Node version you need according to the [NVM docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#usage). I simply used `nvm install node` to install the latest version.
   4. You can reverse step 1 and run the Terminal app without Rosetta support.

You should now be able to run Node with the x86_64 version. (no matter if Terminal is run using Rosetta or not)