# NPM install is not allowing me to specify the Python version

Tags: python, macos, npm, installation, pip

I'm having a new issue with a custom NPM package I'm trying to install with `npm install -g <package-name>`. This package has a "postinstall" step, which runs `pip install`. The requirements are for Python 3 packages, but the pip install fails because it runs in Python 2:

```
> <package-name> postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/<package-name>
> pip install --upgrade -r ./scripts/requirements.txt

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. [...removing for clarity...]
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
[...]
npm ERR! Failed at the <package-name>@<version> postinstall script.
```

I've tried running the global installation in a Python 3 venv environment, and I tried pointing npm to Python 3 with `npm config set python python3.8`, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454199/how-to-use-a-different-version-of-python-during-npm-install). Nothing seems to force the postinstall to run with a Python 3 version of pip, not even specifying the python path directly.

FYI: My [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323911/how-can-i-enforce-the-python-version-for-an-npm-postinstall-step?noredirect=1&lq=1) was closed because of its similarity to the one linked above, but as I said, that didn't help me. Also, I'm on macOS Mojave.

Also, when I run `npm run postinstall` locally - in the directory of the package - I get the same error. If I just run the `pip install` line, it works fine. There's something about using `npm run` here that changes the behavior, but I'm not sure what it is.

This is an internal package maintained by my company. The pip install line is the only postinstall step. It installs a list of requirements including matplotlib >= 3.0 (so Python 3 is required - this is usually where it fails). I changed `pip install` to `python -m pip install`, which actually did use the right python version, then failed in the matplotlib setup. I think that's the key.

Comment: What *is* the package?

Comment: The package is an internal package maintained by my company

Comment: Then there's not much we can do unless you can share a [mre] of the bit that's using pip.

Comment: It's really just the line above, `pip install --upgrade -r ./scripts/requirements.txt`. The requirements include matplotlib>=3.0 which is where it fails. I added a little detail to my post

Answer (score 0):

You tried this commands:

```
  echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7" >> ~/.zshrc
  echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Or use brew?

```
  brew update && brew upgrade python
```

Put this alias on you .rc file if you dont have:

```
  alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

See this page they have a lot of tricks: https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

Comment: I tried adding aliases to ~/.bashrc and it didn't work. I use brew, and I ran `brew update && brew upgrade python` yesterday. The package is an internal package maintained by my company

Comment: You tried change the command to pip3 -> `pip3 install --upgrade -r ./scripts/requirements.txt`?

Comment: No, I don't want to do that since it won't be supported by all machines