# How can I install parcel package using npm install --save-dev parcel?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, parcel

I am trying to install Parcel Webpack, but there are some warnings in this installation. I also checked by deleting the `node_modules` folder but got the same warning every time.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Although it's of course very easy to give instructions on how to solve "some warnings", how about including them in your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are attempting to run uses Python 2 syntax. It is incompatible with Python 3 and when you want to install the package, node-gyp is executed with python3 and this error happened.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454199/how-to-use-a-different-version-of-python-during-npm-install) explain how to change the python version for install package

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link. I tried but none of them woked for me.